# Evaluate $\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{ax}-e^{bx}}{(1+e^{bx})(1+e^{ax})}\,dx$

Tags: calculus

> Evaluate $\int_0^\infty \displaystyle{\frac{e^{ax} - e^{bx}}{(1+e^{bx})(1+e^{ax})}}\,dx$

Can anyone give me some hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming $a, b>0$. Observe we have
\begin{align}
\int^\infty_0 \frac{(e^{ax}+1)-(e^{bx}+1)}{(1+e^{bx})(1+e^{ax})}\ dx =&\ \int^\infty_0 \frac{1}{1+e^{bx}}\ dx-\int^\infty_0 \frac{1}{1+e^{ax}}\ dx\\
=&\ \frac{\log 2}{b}-\frac{\log 2}{a}.
\end{align}

Edit: Observe
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int^n_0 \frac{1}{1+e^{bx}}\ dx =&\ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int^n_0 1-\frac{e^{bx}}{1+e^{bx}}\ dx= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left( x-\frac{\log(1+e^{bx})}{b}\bigg|^n_{x=0}\right)\\
=&\ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left(n-\frac{\log(1+e^{bn})}{b} + \frac{\log 2}{b}\right).
\end{align}
Hence it suffices to show that
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left(n-\frac{\log(1+e^{bn})}{b} \right)=0
\end{align}
which follows from the observation
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\left( x-\log(1+e^x)\right) = 0.
\end{align}

Comment: To evaluate $\int \frac{1}{1+e^{bx}}\,dx$, I integrate $\int 1-\frac{e^{bx}}{1+e^{bx}}\, dx$ instead. However, $\int_2^\infty \frac{1}{u}\, du$ leads to $\log(\infty)-\log(2)$. How to deal with the $\log(\infty)$? Or $\log(\infty)/a$ will cancel out with $\log(\infty)/b$?